# Tag merge: game and game-theory

Tags: discussion

I cannot concieve of a use of [game](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) that does not fall under [game-theory](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory). Please merge the two or delete the former.

Comment: Seems reasonable. This has been completed as requested.